# SSRS - copying and image from report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to copy a graph from an SSRS report, and paste to an email as an image. But either it doesn't copy, or it pastes in white.

I've tried in Chrome and Firefox, to copy to an Outlook email.

I select on the browser, Ctrl-C and then Ctrl-V into the email.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Weird.

However, there is a workaround - copy the graph from the browser, open Paint and paste it in there, then copy it from Paint and paste it into your Outlook email. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. It gets weirder. I right clicked on a graph in the report to copy that specific graph, and when I pasted in Paint, it pasted all the graphs, one below the other. Another option I found is to right click and save the image. But again this may save all the graphs together. Seems I'm sticking to screenshotting for now.